# Chef remote_file from https site with self signed certificate

Tags: ssl, chef-infra

I was wondering if Chef can use a `remote_file` resource form a https source that uses self signed certificate. It doesn't seem to be able to. Documentation does not mention certificates and offer configuration for disable SSL check.

If you have a site with https with self signed certificate this can for example be reproduced with recipe that has

```
remote_file "/tmp/image.png" do
  source "https://mywebsite.com/image.png"
end
```

You can of course use `knife` to fetch the certificate on the target node for example as follows

> vagrant@devops:~$ knife ssl fetch https://mywebsite.com/
>   WARNING: No knife configuration file found
>   WARNING: Certificates from mywebsite.com will be fetched and placed in your trusted_cert directory (/home/vagrant/.chef/trusted_certs).
>   Knife has no means to verify these are the correct certificates. You should
>   verify the authenticity of these certificates after downloading.

This doesn't seem to do much/anything. Chef will continue to show message

> ==> default: [2015-06-08T06:30:33+00:00] ERROR: remote_file[/tmp/image.png] (jenkins::remote_file_test line 1) had an error: OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

Maybe this is a bug? It seems that Chef is ignoring the trusted certs.

Is there a workaround for this? Can we make Chef trust the cert somehow?

**Update**
Correct answer was given by Tensibai. See his comment.

Comment: [ssl_verify_mode = :verify_none](http://docs.chef.io/config_rb_client.html) in `/etc/chef/client.rb` would allow you to disable it completely. It seems, the trusted certs storage is only used for connecting to the chef server also from what I verified now. Right now, I don't see a way except globally disabling verification. Maybe somebody else has a better answer.

Comment: You can get the cacert.pem file from a chef install, insert your own self-signed/internal CA cert into this file and then use a cookbook to deploy it to your nodes. Once the certs are in the cacert.pem (in /opt/chef/embedded/ssl/certs) the ssl validation will work.

Comment: I changed the `client.rb` but the message remains. This is not a workaround it seems.

Comment: I don't have a CA certificate because I am self signing. There is no CA with self signed certificates. Or should I put my certificate pem file in this file? Can I just 'cat' append it to `cacert.pem`?

Comment: @Onno Yes, a self signed cert can be seen as a CA (as it's a top level certificate). And yes if it's base64 encoded you can `cat self-signed.pem >> cacert.pem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `certificate` cookbook to install my self signed certificates. So my solution was based on that. In my recipe I use `certificate_manage` to install certificate which is stored in encrypted data bag.

```
cert_resource = certificate_manage node['hostname'] do
  action :create
  ignore_missing false
end
```

Then I can add certificate to `cacert.pem` with something like

```
ruby_block 'add_self_signed_certificate_to_cacert' do
  block do
    cert_file_path = ::File.join(cert_resource.cert_path, 'certs', cert_resource.cert_file)
    cacert = ::File.read('/opt/chef/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem')
    pem = ::File.read(::File.join(cert_resource.cert_path, 'certs',cert_resource.cert_file))
    unless cacert.include? pem
      File.open('/opt/chef/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem', 'w') {|f| f.write(cacert + "\n" + pem) }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Per tensibai's technique (comment in the original question) I have the following bit of a recipe to install the cert:

```
bash 'pull certificate from gitlab' do
  code <<-EOH
    openssl s_client -connect hqdevgit01.my.lan:443 -showcerts | openssl x509 -outform PEM > /opt/chef/embedded/ssl/certs/gitlab.pem
    cat /opt/chef/embedded/ssl/certs/gitlab.pem >> /opt/chef/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
  EOH
  not_if { ::File.exists?('/opt/chef/embedded/ssl/certs/gitlab.pem') }
end
```

I download and store the pem in a  separate file, and trigger the action off of that existance in the future.  I suppose I should check the cacert.pem, but there doesn't seem to be much problem should the cert be appended more than once.

Ultimately I need to get some certs for my internal tools servers - but the organization is small, and there isn't a clear indication of what and where we will be in 6 months.  This solution is fine (not ideal) for my short term needs (and we are 100% behind firewalls here).

Answer (score 1):

as of chef 12,  the place to put your ca cert file is in `/etc/chef/trusted_certs`.  Putting your file there will resolve this problem.

Comment: That's true for 95% of cases, but when you'll call something using the system openssl lib, having the proper CA certs in a bundle and exporting SSL_CERT_FILE will save your life (and Chef is nice enough to export this variable with its own cacert.pem).

Comment: Where's that location in Windows-land?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you **onknows** for the solution.

On AWS OpsWorks I had same problem when try to download file from remote https source signed by internal CA Authority.

On Windows machine the workaround can be the following.

1. Save in Base-64 encoded X.509 (.CER) the CA Auth certificate.
2. Put the certificate in the cookbook / files directory
3. Copy the certificate on the instance disk (for example using a recipe in the setup phase)

```
cookbook_file 'C:\tmp\calive.cer' do
    source "calive.cer"
    rights :full_control, 'Everyone'
    action :create_if_missing
end
```

4. Add the content of the your CA Auth Certificate to the end of the file:
   **C:\opscode\chef\embedded\ssl\certs\cacert.pem**

```
ruby_block 'install_cert' do
    block do
        filemyca = File.open("c:\\tmp\\calive.cer").readlines
        open("C:\\opscode\\chef\\embedded\\ssl\\certs\\cacert.pem", 'a') do |f|
            f.puts ""
            f.puts "My Internel CA Auth Cert"
            f.puts "==========================================="
            f.puts filemyca
        end
    end
    action :run
end
```

4. Execute the remote file copy

```
mypath = 'https://mysite.mydom.local/the_file'
mylocalfile = "c://mydir//the_file"
remote_file mylocalfile do
    source mypath
    action :create_if_missing
end
```